# How to show a field in views only when a checkbox is ticked?

Tags: entities, views

I want the user to be able to choose whether to show a description or not for each node in the view. Adding the filter only works on the entire object, I just want to show/hide one field. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what code have you tried? Take this question and strip "Drupal" from it. You have a listing and you want to toggle a <div> as shown or not-shown. Javascript can propbably do this. You probably want to look at the Form API, hook_form_alter() and the `#states` FAPI element in the Drupal API. Or, just just custom jQuery on the page ...

Comment: @Sergo, when you say you 'want the user to be able to choose' do you mean that you want to toggle between showing all description fields (where present) and hiding all description fields, using a toggle / dropdown akin to the normal Views exposed filters. Or do you mean that the user (who is editing the node) needs to be able to tick a box to make some text appear or not when the node is shown in a listing (my interpretation for the answer I've given). Or something else again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with Views out of the box. No need for Views PHP here.

1. Add your boolean field in Views. (This assumes the default boolean set up, i.e. 0 for not checked and 1 for checked.)
2. Use the **Key** formatter - this isn't obvious, but I couldn't get it to work without this.
3. Select **REWRITE RESULTS** and put the description you want in there. This can include tokens so you can grab material from other fields in the node if that's what you need.
4. On **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR** check all the boxes (Count the number 0 as empty, Hide if empty, Hide rewriting if empty)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with th [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

Set up your view with the checkbox and description fields included but not visible. Then include a Global:PHP field, and under the field configuration put something like:

```
<?php
echo ($row->checkbox) ? $row->description : '';
?>
```

in the Display box.

Comment: ["While this module allows you to directly use PHP inside views which may be useful for quick and easy solutions, it is **highly advisable** to use regular handlers and plugins when available (or even to create one yourself). Take note that filtering and sorting a view using PHP always has a considerable perfomance impact."](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)